# How to put a required validation in this case?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not using a form to submit the answer, so the "required" command does not work. Instead after the user press the button, I save the answer in a variable to display later.

```
 <!-- First Question = 1 -->
        <section class="container-fluid section" id="1" style="display: block;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 top">
                    <span id="back-btn" class="question-previous badge badge-pill badge-dark" onclick="back0()">Voltar</span>
                    <span class="question-progress">1/15</span>
                    <a href="#"><h1 class="logo">norun</h1></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 question-title">
                    <h2>Nome da empresa</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 question-input">
                    <input autofocus type="text" id="answer1" class="input-field">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 submit-button">
                    <button onclick="next1();" type="button" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Second Question = 2 -->
        <section class="container-fluid section" id="2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 top">
                    <span class="question-previous badge badge-pill badge-dark" onclick="back1()">Voltar</span>
                    <span class="question-progress">2/15</span>
                    <a href="#"><h1 class="logo">norun</h1></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 question-title">
                    <h2>Ramo de atuação</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 question-input">
                    <input type="text" id="answer2" class="input-field">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 submit-button">
                    <button onclick="next2();" type="button" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could archive the same by adding a form with the onsubmit value an return false at the end:

```
<section class="container-fluid section" id="1" style="display: block;">
    <form onsubmit="next1(); return false">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 top">
                <span id="back-btn" class="question-previous badge badge-pill badge-dark" onclick="back0()">Voltar</span>
                <span class="question-progress">1/15</span>
                <a href="#"><h1 class="logo">norun</h1></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 question-title">
                <h2>Nome da empresa</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 question-input">
                <input autofocus type="text" id="answer1" class="input-field">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 submit-button">
                <input type="submit" type="button" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

this would also have the benefit that the user can use standard form functions like arrow and tab keys and so on